# SWTBot cannot copy/paste on tree items using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: java, swt, swtbot

I want to copy/paste between two `SWTBotTreeItem` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Using copy/paste with the context menu works well, but I am required to use keyboard shortcuts too.
The following code doesn't work: I can't copy the first node.

```
SWTBotTreeItem node1 = parentNode.getNode(name1);
SWTBotTreeItem node2 = parentNode.getNode(name2);
node1.select().pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL, 'C');
node2.select().pressShortcut(SWT.CTRL, 'V');
```

Even if I use 'copy' on node1 via the contextMenu, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on node2 does nothing.

I would like to understand what mistake I've done when using the pressShortcut.